# Deploying entitlements through SOAP API

Tags: soap-api, metadata-api, entitlements

I'm trying to deploy entitlement object meta data, layouts, and fields through the SOAP API. However, I keep getting an error:

```
 Invalid fullName, must end in a custom suffix ( for ex. __c )
```

As a result, anything else in packaged for deployment that is dependent on the entitlement object also fails to deploy. Such as page layouts, apex code that uses, entitlement object, etc.

```
In field: layout - no Layout named Entitlement-Entitlement Layout found
Parent entity failed to deploy
```

Thanks,

Comment: Did you make sure Entitlements are enabled for the org?

Comment: @sfdcfox that was it! Although, the sfdx tool has limitations with certain objects. But main issue has to do with entitlements not being enabled.

Comment: You might be interested in the new "org shape" pilot; it lets you configure a scratch org identically to your production org. That might help you. See [this post](https://t.co/HgYwEidMGs).